# Series Expansion of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, radicals

I am trying to expand this function around $x_0=0$.

Using Mathematica I get 
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}-\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^{\frac{5}{2}})$$

I somehow manage to calculate the first term by hand, even though I don't know if it is correct.

But I don't understand how to calculate the higher order terms.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a pretty big problem at $x=0$.

Comment: how did you find the first term?

Comment: You might prefer to find a series expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}=1 - \frac12x - \frac18x^2 - \frac1{16}x^3 - \frac5{128}x^4 + O(x^5)$.  If you then divide the result by $\sqrt{x}$, this demonstrates the issue at $x=0$

Comment: If you just require the expansion to converge on a punctured nbd of $a$, then note that, $$\sqrt{1/x-1}=\frac 1{\sqrt x}(1-x)^{1/2}=\frac 1{\sqrt x}\left(1-\frac x2+\frac{(1/2)(1/2-1)}{2!}x^2+\mathcal O(x^3)\right)=\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you very much Henry, now I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{1-x}
$$

and

$$
\sqrt{1-x} = 1+\frac{1}{2}(-x)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\frac{(-x)^2}{2!}+\cdots
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{{1\over x}-1}=(1-x)^{1/2}x^{-1/2}$$

$$\begin{align}
(1-x)^{1/2}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}(-1)^kx^k\\
&={1}-{\frac12\over1!}x^1+{\frac12(\frac12-1)\over2!}x^2-{\frac12(\frac12-1)(\frac12-2)\over3!}x^3\dots
\end{align}$$

Just multiply this series by $x^{-1/2}$ and you'll get the answer

Comment: The first term is $1$, not $1/2$.

Comment: yep, i goofed up. editing it